# set attribute using dynamic value from drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here i want to set a attribute "selected" in a dynamic drop down when it is clicked after HttpPost in MVC it shows the same first text "Please select a category".

```
@if (Model.objlist1.Count != 0) {
    <select id="catID" onchange="getID();this.form.submit();">
        <option id="removeIT" value="007">Please select a category</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.objlist1) {
            //a++;
            <option value="@item.categoryID">@item.category</option>
        }
    </select>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.categoryID, new { @id = "newCatID", @name = "newCatID" })
}
```

After reload from HttpPost i want to get the "selected" attribute in the dynamic drop down within foreach loop option tag by using the value to check and set attribute "selected" in option tag.

Answer (score 0):

try like this 
In backend pass category

```
 ViewData["category"] =  new SelectList(
new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cat1", Value = 1},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cat2", Value = 2},
}, "Value" , "Text");
```

in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.categoryID,  ViewData["category"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Please select a category")
```

Comment: but how can i set attribute "selected" in view page rather then backend category because as you can see above i use foreach loop on option tag i want it in that way.

Comment: it will automatically select depend on value

Comment: issue resolved added the value from option tag to viewbag and then set it on $("#catID").val('@ViewBag.ID') inside document ready function